# The "-bash: ls: command not found" error occurs on my MAC

Tags: macos, terminal, path

I installed ant and added the ant to the path in .bash_profile file on my MAC yesterday,ant can work sucessfully.Below is my .bash_profile file:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin/:$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin


#$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/ADT/sdk
#export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

export ANT_HOME=/Users/helendai/apache-ant-1.10.7
export PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin

JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home

CLASSPAHT=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar

#PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH:

export JAVA_HOME

export CLASSPATH

export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
#PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

but error occurs when I run other basic commands such as "ls、vim"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xsHA.png)

I tried this way can solve this problem **temporarily**：
run below command:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/helendai/apache-ant-1.10.7/bin:”
```

but when I restart the terminal，error occurs again "-bash: ls: command not found".How can I solve this problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7JBC.png)

Comment: The problem is `export PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin`, you should put `export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few simple errors going on here.  `export PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin` is overwriting PATH instead of appending to the end.  use `export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin` instead.
Also `CLASSPAHT=` is defined but you are exporting `CLASSPATH` to the shell.